# Does this matrix have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, terminology

If $L$ is a lower triangular matrix of ones, does the following matrix have a special name?

$$A = \left(\begin{matrix}L &  -L \\
           -L & L \end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: It might be $\pmatrix{1 &-1\\ -1 &1}\otimes L$. ($\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product)

Comment: What does this have to do with graph theory?

Comment: well I had it written as part of a solution to an LP formulation of a flow network, so perhaps graph theorists could have a better idea on what it's called.

Answer (score 1):

It's a special type of "[block matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix)".  Or, as user13838 points out, it can be described as a [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) (or direct product).

(Or, you could just call it $A$.)